# Is there a macro to draw Ferrers shapes?

Tags: graphics

Is there a macro to draw Ferrers shapes? 
Ideally, I am looking for a macro where I just have to put in the numbers, 
say, 5,3,2, and it will draw a picture of a Ferrers shape with row lengths 5,3,2.
Best would be something that does not require packages like tikz.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is "Ferrers Shape"? Please explain your question better, for example with an image ...

Comment: ... and please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried so far...

Comment: Yes, there are the `young`, `youngtab` and `ytableau` packages. `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{youngtab}\begin{document}\yng(5,3,2)\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\begin{document}
\yng(5,3,2)

If you call this Young tableau $\vcenter{\hbox{\yng(5,3,2)}}$ a Ferrer diagram
you'll find at least three packages that can draw such things for you:
\texttt{young}, \texttt{youngtab} and \texttt{ytableau}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a Young tableau once you put numbers in it.

Comment: @MiklosBona I was under the impression that you do not fill it with numbers to call it Young tableau.

Comment: If you area interested, please see
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/YoungTableau.html 
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @MiklosBona If you are interested, look at any book on group theory or the standard literature of high energy physics.